# Condition between Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do 2 checks in my DataFrame, and them, save the result in a new variable.
I am trying to see IF the column 'RBS_Type' contains the string Baseband. If so, check the other column called 'RBS_Model' if the content NOT EXIST in the Vector BASEBAND, and return to 'DATA_ALL_NODES_WRONG_RBSTYPE ' just this result.
But something is wrong, could you help me?

```
BASEBAND = ['6620', '6630', '5212', '5216', '6502']

DATA_ALL_NODES_WRONG_RBSTYPE = DATA_ALL_NODES_CONTENT_ELIS[(DATA_ALL_NODES_CONTENT_ELIS['RBS_Type'] == 'Baseband')and (DATA_ALL_NODES_CONTENT_ELIS.loc[~DATA_ALL_NODES_CONTENT_ELIS['RBS_Model'].isin(BASEBAND)])]
```

---

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/ejhosou/PycharmProjects/ELIS_LK/LKF_VIVO_REVB.py", line 564, in <module>
        DATA_ALL_NODES_WRONG_RBSTYPE = DATA_ALL_NODES_CONTENT_ELIS[(DATA_ALL_NODES_CONTENT_ELIS['RBS_Type'] == 'Baseband')and (DATA_ALL_NODES_CONTENT_ELIS.loc[~DATA_ALL_NODES_CONTENT_ELIS['RBS_Model'].isin(BASEBAND)])]
      File "C:\Users\ejhosou\PycharmProjects\ELIS_LK\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1327, in __nonzero__
        f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Why do you use all-caps????

Comment: `and` works for a scalar, use bitwise `&` for arrays and series

Comment: @DYZ Why nitpick on using all-caps? Unless he uses all caps in keywords where it would not be used. It is personal preference to use all-caps for variables. If you noticed he used all-caps for keywords where capitalisation is important then say so, otherwise your comment doesn't help.

Comment: @TheGrandJ Wrong, it is not personal preference. According to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), all-cap identifiers are reserved for constants. The OP violates the naming convention.

Comment: @DYZ Then say that! Just saying why doesn't help the question. If the convention is a requirement and not just a visual aid then let the asker know. Just asking why followed by multiple question marks is kinda aggressive (In my opinion at least).

Answer (score 0):

I will change de all-cap later jajaja.
Back to my problem ( still in all-cap ), now I have this:

```
DATA_ALL_NODES_WRONG_RBSTYPE = (DATA_ALL_NODES_CONTENT_ELIS[DATA_ALL_NODES_CONTENT_ELIS['RBS_Type'] == 'Baseband']) & (DATA_ALL_NODES_CONTENT_ELIS.loc[~DATA_ALL_NODES_CONTENT_ELIS['RBS_Model'].isin(BASEBAND)])
```

Error:

```
result = libops.vec_binop(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), op)
```

File "pandas_libs\ops.pyx", line 249, in pandas._libs.ops.vec_binop
File "pandas_libs\ops.pyx", line 242, in pandas._libs.ops.vec_binop
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'